# select between two dates ms access using php

Tags: php, date, ms-access

i want to select data from ms access using php
here is my code :

```
$dbdir = "D:\payroll2\ATT2000.MDB";
$conn = odbc_connect("DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=$dbdir", 
  "administrator", 
  "");
$b = 4104;
$jo = date('n/j/Y h:i:s A',strtotime('2016-01-21 00:00:01'));
$ji = date('n/j/Y h:i:s A',strtotime('2016-01-21 23:59:59'));

$sql = "SELECT TOP 20 * from CHECKINOUT inner join USERINFO on CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID where USERINFO.SSN = '$b'";
$rs = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
odbc_fetch_row($rs, 0); 

while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) { 

echo odbc_result($rs,"CHECKTIME"); print('<br>');

} 
 odbc_close($conn);
}
```

it works fine , but i want to select data between two dates
so i add  `AND CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME between '$jo' and '$ji'` into the query like this :

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 20 * from CHECKINOUT inner join USERINFO on CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID where USERINFO.SSN = '$b' AND CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME between '$jo' and '$ji'";
```

i dont know why it doest work,
im sure the data is exist and my date format was persist like the ms access date format.

any help will appreciated,
im sorry for my bad english..

Comment: What is the datatype and format of date stored in Database?

Comment: @Samir the data type is Date/Time , and its the sample data from the row 2/4/2011 4:20:28 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With MSAccess & MS SQL Server also I believe you need to use hash signs around the dates and you might also need to use `CDate()` to ensure the date is recognised as a date.

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 20 * from CHECKINOUT 
    inner join USERINFO on CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID 
    where USERINFO.SSN = '$b' AND CDate( CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME ) between '#{$jo}#' and '#{$ji}#'";
```