# Select between two dates MS Access and php

Tags: php, ms-access

I would like to select data from Ms Access Database between two data and time in PHP.

I used this code.

```
$dbc = odbc_connect("Attend", "", "");
if(!$dbc) {
    exit("Cannection Faild");
}

$in = date('n/j/Y h:i:s',strtotime('2019-01-30 00:00:01'));
$out = date('n/j/Y h:i:s',strtotime('2019-01-30 23:59:59'));

$query = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE USERID = 214 AND CDate(CHECKTIME) between '$in' and '$out'";

$results = odbc_exec($dbc, $query);

if(!$results) {
    exit("Error in SQL");
}

while (odbc_fetch_row($results)) {
    echo odbc_result($results, "CHECKTIME")."<br/>";
}

odbc_close($dbc);
```

But this is nothing showed. But if I change the in date and out date with this:

```
$in = date('n/j/Y h:i:s',strtotime('2019-01-29 00:00:01'));
$out = date('n/j/Y h:i:s',strtotime('2019-01-31 23:59:59'));
```

it will display unexpected results. Like below:

```
2018-01-03 08:26:52
2018-01-03 20:19:09
2018-01-30 07:55:38
2018-01-30 14:37:09
2019-01-30 11:48:27
2019-01-30 12:17:26
2019-01-30 12:38:33
2019-01-30 13:29:27
2019-01-30 14:15:20
2019-01-30 18:11:27
2019-01-30 19:09:10
2019-01-30 19:28:43
2019-01-31 10:28:51
```

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34918341/11040153). But it doesn't work. This is nothing show.

So, where I need to change?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried to query Access DB from PHP, but since you are using ODBC there should not be any difference as with other programming languages

Give this a try

```
$in = '2019-01-30 00:00:01';
$out = '2019-01-30 23:59:59';

$query = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE USERID = 214 AND CDate(CHECKTIME) between #$in# and #$out#";
```

Dates should be surrounded by `#` in MS Access SQL.

And I don't see a reason to transform your strings in dates first, because MS access will recognize your strings as dates if you surround them with `#`, and they should be parsed correctly if you use the standard international format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Additionally, the `CDate()` should not be necessary if the CHECKTIME column is properly defined as date in the database

Answer (score 0):

In format lose AM/PM

```
'n/j/Y h:i:s A'
```