# Passing dates from PHP to fetch data from Microsoft Access

Tags: php, html, sql, ms-access-2016

I am trying to get data from Microsoft access database by passing value from two datepickers by the name of from and to. I am creating a php website but i just cant get ms access to return me the data i want.

**This is my current code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Date Query</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label for="from">From :</label>
        <input type="date" id="from" name="from">
        <label for="to">To :</label>
        <input type="date" id="to" name="to">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $from=$_POST['from'];
        $to=$_POST['to'];

        $conn = odbc_connect("Ingot_Daily_Report", "", "");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM Output_Data WHERE data_Day BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
        $sql = odbc_exec($conn, $query);
        while($row=odbc_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo $row['data_Day'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['KPI_Daily_Target'];
            echo "<br><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

The between clause is not returning me any data but when i remove the between clause, the sql fetches me all the data available in the database table. Is there a syntax or operator that i should use or any changing of date format to retrieve the correct set of data ?

My data_Day column is in shortText format. I want the returning data to be in between those two dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select between two dates ms access using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916969/select-between-two-dates-ms-access-using-php)

Comment: No Sir/Madam. Ive tried the solution yet my query returns me empty data. @flakerimi

Answer (score 1):

After some hard findings, i added the # sign before and after my php variable in the SQL query. The reason behind this is because Microsoft Access seems to only recognize data in between # signs as date format.

**Before**

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM Output_Data WHERE data_Day BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
```

**After**

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM Output_Data WHERE data_Day BETWEEN #$from# AND #$to#";
```

And I used date() and strtotime() function to change my format of date from the datepicker

```
date("Y/m/d",strtotime(@@php variable with date value stored inside@@));
```

Lastly, i change my column data format into date/time under short date in order for these codes to work.